# Im using python (django framework) to gain a request token from google api, but the request token always comes back empty

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

Here is sample code that I'm working with.

```
def index(request):                     
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id='xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        client_secret='xyz',
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
        user_agent='sample/1.0')

callback = 'http://%s/oauth2callback' % request.META[ 'HTTP_HOST' ]
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url(callback)

return HttpResponse(flow)
```

For some reason 'flow' is always set to " " or empty instead of a request token. I have searched for days on this issue.
Can anyone tell me why I can't get a request token from google using this method?

fyi: I know that I should be redirecting the user to the authorize url, but I want to see if flow is set before I do since Google will provide the authorize url even if a request token wasn't returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before you can use OAuth 2.0, you must register your application using
>   the Google APIs Console. After you've registered, go to the API Access
>   tab and copy the "Client ID" and "Client secret" values, which you'll
>   need later.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2#Registering

If this answer actually helps with your problem then I must bid an R.I.P. to S.O.

Comment: Hey John thanks for responding. I actually already did that part and the api console provided me with a client id and secret that I use. My specific issue was with actually gaining a request token that I have to persist so that I can use it to gain an access token later on in my script. I assume that "flow" is suppose to be set to the request token that google provides.